# Facebook ip address for access my database because of OG meta tags

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, ip-address, meta

I tried facebook debugger with articles on my website. I use argument "n" as ID of news. But with this argument, debugger returns error with code 404. Other sites works fine. I am getting news data from database above html part.

This is my php snippet:

```
<?php
    function truncate_text($body, $max_length){ if (strlen($body) > $max_length) { return strip_tags(substr($body, 0, strrpos(substr($body, 0, $max_length + 1), ' '))) . '...'; } return strip_tags($body); }

    if(isset($content)){
        $descriptionText = truncate_text($content, 150);
        echo "<meta name='description' content='" . $descriptionText . "'>\n";
        echo "<meta name='og:description' content='" . $descriptionText . "'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='og:title' content='SDH Prostřední Bečva - " . $header . "'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='og:type' content='article'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='article:author' content='https://www.facebook.com/sdh.prostrednibecva'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='article:publisher' content='https://www.facebook.com/sdh.prostrednibecva'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='og:url' content='https://www.sdhbecva.cz/aktualita?n=" . $newsID . "'>\n";
        if($imagesCount != 0){
            echo "<meta property='og:image' content='https://www.sdhbecva.cz/news/" . $newsID . "/full/1.jpg'>\n";
            echo "<meta property='og:image:secure_url' content='https://www.sdhbecva.cz/news/" . $newsID . "/full/1.jpg'>\n";
        } else{
            echo "<meta property='og:image' content='https://www.sdhbecva.cz/images/ogImage1.png'>\n";
            echo "<meta property='og:image:secure_url' content='https://www.sdhbecva.cz/images/ogImage1.png'>\n";
            echo "<meta property='og:image:width' content='1279px'>\n";
            echo "<meta property='og:image:height' content='719px'>\n";
        }

    } else{
        echo "<meta name='description' content='Oficiální stránky hasičů Prostřední Bečvy. Příjďte se podívat na nové a aktuální informace, výjezdy, fotky, videa a další.'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='og:description' content='Oficiální stránky hasičů Prostřední Bečvy. Příjďte se podívat na nové a aktuální informace, výjezdy, fotky, videa a další.'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='og:title' content='SDH Prostřední Bečva - aktuální informace, výjezdy, fotky, videa a další'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='og:type' content='website'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='og:url' content='https://www.sdhbecva.cz/'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='og:image' content='https://www.sdhbecva.cz/images/ogImage1.png'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='og:image:secure_url' content='https://www.sdhbecva.cz/images/ogImage1.png'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='og:image:width' content='1279px'>\n";
        echo "<meta property='og:image:height' content='719px'>\n";
    }


     ?>
```

[Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DzUe.png)  [Screen2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5Eni.jpg)

Comment: You have an example of a URL that doesn't work?

Comment: https://sdhbecva.cz/aktualita.php?n=7

Comment: I think, problem is in blocking facebook access to my database. But I dont know which IP allow in Czech Republic.

Comment: I highly doubt that. https://sdhbecva.cz/ works.

Comment: I included two screenshots at the end of my question and there is can be seen.

Comment: I mean I highly doubt it is an IP allow problem because one works. I'm guessing someone is wrong on your server

Comment: Yes, it works when you are on the page. But Facebook load it from his side, I think. My localhost didnt work too, until I allowed my public IP for database.

Comment: I figured it out. It was mistake in og:url...I had there aktualita instead of aktualita.php... And database works fine without facebook ip access.